# Does establishing a proxy pass to CloudFront via NGINX preserve the benefits of CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following configuration on NGINX:

```
location ~ ^/app/ {
  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_pass https://my-cloudfront-distribution.cloudfront.net;
}
```

Is this sufficient for enabling all the cache features from cloudfront? Meaning, that, wouldn't CloudFront think that all the requests come from the NGINX server?

Comment: This would certainly destroy the benefits of CloudFront's edge network. Instead of having CloudFront respond from cache nodes that are close to the user's location, all requests would be going through this one NGINX server, which could be far away from the user, and then to one single CloudFront edge location. Why do you feel the need to setup NGINX in front of CloudFront, instead of setting up CloudFront in front of NGINX? With your proposed setup you'd be better off just setting up caching directly in NGINX.

Comment: @MarkB it's the only solution I have found to my particular problem.

Comment: Perhaps  you should post a new question that describes the actual problem you are trying to solve.